# awk command to delete duplicate lines from tcl file and print into another tcl file

Tags: awk, tcl

I am trying to delete duplicate lines from one file and outputting it into another file. I used awk command for this purpose but an error keeps showing up. What is the exact awk command to be used

Comment: What does the error say?

Comment: awk '!x[$2]++' fil1.tcl > newfile.tcl
can't read "2": no such variable

Comment: I used the above command and this error keeps coming up. Should i read file and then set the variable?

Comment: Please add sample data to this question, and elaborate on what exactly you want to do.

Comment: I have the following lines in my file

Comment: ABC (10 TIMES) I want to delete remaining 9 lines and print this 1 line which is unique. and i want to print this in another file

Comment: So you are not interested in duplicate lines, but lines with the same value in column two?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$2` means the second field in record. `$0` means the whole record, so how about:

```
awk '!x[$0]++' fil1.tcl > newfile.tcl
```

Testing it:

```
$ for i in 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 ; do echo ABC >> fil1.tcl ; done
$ awk '!x[$0]++' fil1.tcl
ABC
$
```

Comment: As long as the Tcl commands in the input script are never multi-line, that'll be fine. (It's one of these things that sounds trivial and is… with _test_ data. With real life data, stuff gets messy…)